# Replace all the occurrences of a sub-string that matches certain pattern in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server-2014-express

I want to replace all the occurrences of the pattern `AI[0-9][0-9][0-9]` with another string so that the final output would be like :

Input string:

```
'blah blah bhal AI dbo.AI001abc AI787abc AIWS find AI333xyz'
```

Output string:

```
'blah blah bhal AI dbo.AI001abc op.AI787abc AIWS find op.AI333xyz'
```

In other words if `AI[0-9][0-9][0-9]` pattern is found, I need to append `"op."`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The "all occurrences" part of your requirement is tricky.  If you knew you only had one occurrence, there would be a fairly straightforward way to do this using `PATINDEX` with `STUFF`.  But for an arbitrary number of occurrences, I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Probably the most appropriate tool here would be a regex all replacement.  But, SQL Server 2014 does not have native support for this.  You could look into using a UDF.

Comment: If it's an UPDATE to correct an existing table you could loop-while-patindex

Comment: Thank you all guys to putting time. My task is to update all the views, functions and procedures that has the table name with pattern '%[AI|ai][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'. I don't know if my input is sufficient. Please let me know for more input.